# SharpGL Animation Questions

Tags: performance, opengl, animation, graphics, sharpgl

So I am writing a program that parses files with xyz points and makes a bunch of connected lines. What I am trying to do is animate each line being drawn. I have tried to use VBO's and Display Lists in order to increase performance (as I am dealing with large amount of data points i.e. 1,000,000 points) but I could not figure out how to use them in SharpGL. So the code I am using to draw right now is as follows:

```
private void drawInput(OpenGL gl)
            {

                gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_LINE_STRIP);
                for (int i = 0; i < parser.dataSet.Count; i++)
                {


                    gl.Color((float) i, 3.0f, 0.0f);
                    gl.Vertex(parser.dataSet[i].X, parser.dataSet[i].Y, parser.dataSet[i].Z);
                    gl.Flush();
                }
                gl.End();

            }
```

I know immediate mode is super noobzore5000 of me, but I can't find any SharpGL examples of VBO's or Display Lists. So know what I want to do is to 'redraw' the picture after each line is drawn. I thought when the flush method is called, it draws everything up to that point. But it still 'batches' it, and displays all the data at once, how can I animate this? I am incredibly desperate, I don't think thoroughly learning OpenGL or DirectX is practical for such a simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of tinkering, I chose to go with OpenTK because I did end up figuring out VBO's for SharpGL and the performance is AWFUL compared to OpenTK. I will give an answer as to how to animate in the way that I wanted.

My solution works with Immediate Mode and using VBO's. The main concept is making a member integer (animationCount) that you increase every time your paint function gets called, and paint up to that number.

Immediate Mode:

```
private void drawInput(OpenGL gl)
        {

            gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_LINE_STRIP);
            for (int i = 0; i < animationCount; i++)
            {


                gl.Color((float) i, 3.0f, 0.0f);
                gl.Vertex(parser.dataSet[i].X, parser.dataSet[i].Y, parser.dataSet[i].Z);
            }
            gl.End();

            animationCount++;
        }
```

or

VBO:

```
 private void glControl1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
 {
 GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, 0, animationCount);
 animationCount++;
 }
```

Comment: The first code snippet will produce OpenGL errors. Calling `glFlush()` between `glBegin()` and `glEnd()` results in a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error. It would also be incredibly slow if it worked.

Comment: Oops I forgot to remove that. However the question is how to animate, not how to increase performance. The above solutions work, however long they may take.